# Datamapper - Find each client by project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, sinatra, datamapper

I'd like to view each Project by Client, but unsure how to use Datamapper to get this information out. I have my relationships setup like this:

```
class Client
    property :id, Serial
    property  :name, String
    has n, :projects, :foreign_key => "company_id"
end

class Project
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property  :title, String
  belongs_to :company, "Client"
  has n, :stages
end
```

I would like to output a list like:

Client 1

- Project A
- Project B
- Project C

Client 2

- Project D
- Project E

What's the best way to get this out of Datamapper and what would the view template look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataMapper has not foreign_key option. It's `:child_key`

So you need change your Client model

```
class Client
    property :id, Serial
    property  :name, String
    has n, :projects, 'Project', :child_key => [:company_id]
end
```

After you can iterate on all project by client

```
<% Client.all.each do |client| %>
<%= client.name %>
<ul>
  <% client.projects.each do |project| %>
  <li><%= project.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, In the database my Projects table now has a company_id which is correct. However view is only outputting the the client name and nothing inside client.projects.each, any way I can debug?

Comment: Yep, I've got: ~ (0.000582) SELECT "id", "name", "client_slug" FROM "clients" ORDER BY "id"
 ~ (0.000094) SELECT "id", "title", "project_id" FROM "projects" WHERE "project_id" IN (2, 14, 15, 19, 20, 24, 28, 42, 43) ORDER BY "id""

Comment: And if you add 'Project' args in your has_n. I update my answers for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Find all clients (this should go in a controller of some kind)
@clients = Client.all # Maybe you want to order them here too
```

View...

```
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
<%= client.name %>
<ul>
  <% client.projects.each do |project| %>
  <li><%= project.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That gives me a 'condition :foreign_key does not map to a property or relationship in MyApp::Project'

Do I not need to do Projects.all() somewhere?